# How to return an entire Datastore table by name using Node.js on a Google Cloud Function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I want to retrieve a table (with all rows) by name. I want to HTTP request using something like this on the body `{"table": user}`.

Tried this code without success:

```
'use strict';

const {Datastore} = require('@google-cloud/datastore');

// Instantiates a client
const datastore = new Datastore();

exports.getUsers = (req, res) => {

//Get List
const query = this.datastore.createQuery('users');
this.datastore.runQuery(query).then(results => {
  const customers = results[0];
  console.log('User:');
  customers.forEach(customer => {
    const cusKey = customer[this.datastore.KEY];
    console.log(cusKey.id);
    console.log(customer);
  });
})
.catch(err => { console.error('ERROR:', err); });


}
```

Comment: Howdy and welcome to StackOverflow.  When posting questions, please try and assist the readers.  For example, in your question you said "Tried this code without success" ... Can you elaborate?  What DID happen vs what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Google Datastore** is a NoSQL database that is working with entities and not tables. What you want is to load all the "records" which are "key identifiers" in Datastore and all their "properties", which is the "columns" that you see in the Console. But you want to load them based the "Kind" name which is the "table" that you are referring to.

Here is a solution on how to retrieve all the key identifiers and their properties from Datastore, using HTTP trigger Cloud Function running in Node.js 8 environment.

1. Create a Google Cloud Function and choose the trigger to HTTP.
2. Choose the runtime to be Node.js 8
3. In index.js replace all the code with [this GitHub code](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Support/blob/master/Datastore/load_records_node.js).
4. In package.json add:

```js
    {
      "name": "sample-http",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/datastore": "^3.1.2"
      }
    }
```

5. Under **Function to execute** add `loadDataFromDatastore`, since this is the name of the function that we want to execute.

> NOTE: This will log all the loaded records into the Stackdriver logs
>   of the Cloud Function. The response for each record is a JSON,
>   therefore you will have to convert the response to a JSON object to
>   get the data you want. Get the idea and modify the code accordingly.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help