# Google Cloud Function/google-auth-library: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, gcloud, google-api-js-client

Following this: https://medium.com/@nedavniat/how-to-perform-and-schedule-firestore-backups-with-google-cloud-platform-and-nodejs-be44bbcd64ae

Code is:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions'); // is installed automatically when you init the project
const { auth } = require('google-auth-library'); // is used to authenticate your request

async function exportDB () {
    const admin = await auth.getClient({
        scopes: [                               // scopes required to make a request
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/datastore',
            'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'
        ]
    });
    const projectId = await auth.getProjectId();
    const url = `https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/${projectId}/databases/(default):exportDocuments`;
    return admin.request({
        url,
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            outputUriPrefix: 'gs://name-of-the-bucket-you-created-for-backups'
        }
    });
}
```

const backup = functions.pubsub.topic('YOUR_TOPIC_NAME_HERE').onPublish(exportDB);
module.exports = { backup };

When I go to deploy via:

```
gcloud functions deploy backup --runtime nodejs8 --trigger-topic YOUR_TOPIC_NAME_HERE
```

I get error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3,
>   message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Code in
>   file index.js can't be loaded. Is there a syntax error in your code?
>
> Detailed stack trace: TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of
>   undefined

Is this something with google-auth-library?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to deploy GCF function triggered by HTTP request, I suggest you to check this link[1] seems is the same use case and can help you to use Google Cloud Datastore with node.js on GCF

[1] [How to return an entire Datastore table by name using Node.js on a Google Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388299/how-to-return-an-entire-datastore-table-by-name-using-node-js-on-a-google-cloud)